# What would cause a sudden spike in the battery charge level?

Tags: battery, nexus-7, 4.3-jelly-bean

Today I spotted something this on the battery chart :

[image: graph of battery history showing a massive spike]
<sup>graph of battery history showing a massive spike (click for larger variant)</sup>

What is the reason of such erection ? Hardware problem ? Or maybe a bug ? Should I report it or is it a common problem with battery charts ?

PS: It was spotted in Nexus 7 (2013)

Comment: Uhhhh.... I really do not know what to say to the title! xD Did you plug it in at the point prior to the spike? If not, I'd check the health of the battery, i.e. not lumpy, and that is discharging normally. If battery is ok, then check around with other users... admittedly never seen that before, chances are its a bug, somewhat! What Android is this - 4.3?

Comment: Right, it is not rooted original stock Android 4.3

Comment: Ok, This could be a glitch with Android 4.3, perhaps you should consider checking around first if *you're certain that the battery is healthy*, apparently googling **android 4.3 battery spike** yielded this [linky](http://www.neowin.net/news/nexus-4-owners-frustrated-over-android-43-update-which-threatens-to-brick-phones) quoting *Signal loss, continuous reboot loops, application bugs and battery life issues are just a few of the myriad of problems reported hours after the update was released.*